# Want to delete a set of data from firestore in my ionic 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, ionic4

i was able to upload and fetch data from firestore but the issue is deleting the data collected. Below is my code 
 My services

```
        delete_AcBooking(record_id) {
   return this.afirestore.doc(`users/${this.user.getUID()}/AcBooking` + record_id).delete();
}
```

component.ts

```
    RemoveRecord(rowID) {
  this.bookingservice.delete_AcBooking(rowID);
}
```

error

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/pht1VUEXbFfkD3udB9Q3cMwWtcH2/AcBookingLHF9Yj9JkoFpaUOsJtpd has 3
at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85176:28)
at Function.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.DocumentReference.forPath (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:105305:19)
at Firestore.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.Firestore.doc (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:105091:34)
at AngularFirestore.push../node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.js.AngularFirestore.doc (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:67496:34)
at BookingServiceService.push../src/app/service/booking-service.service.ts.BookingServiceService.delete_AcBooking (http://localhost:4200/main.js:5076:25)
at BookingsPage.push../src/app/pages/bookings/bookings.page.ts.BookingsPage.RemoveRecord (http://localhost:4200/pages-bookings-bookings-module.js:333:29)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///BookingsPageModule/BookingsPage.ngfactory.js:44:31)
at handleEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65419:41)
at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:66489:25)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:66216:12)
```

Comment: Side note: have you read the docs about deleting? There are a number of complications with deleting sets of data and it's not recommended to do it on the client side. [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing some `/`. Try following:

```
this.afirestore.doc(`users/${this.user.getUID()}/AcBooking/${record_id}`).delete();
```

or do:

```
return this.afirestore
  .collection('users')
  .doc(this.user.getUID())
  .collection('AcBooking')
  .doc(record_id)
  .delete()
```

Here I assume `AcBooking` is a collection.